# Eclipse juno jboss5.1 unable to choose deploy foudler

Tags: eclipse, jboss5.x, eclipse-juno, jboss-tools

I've upgraded eclipse to juno and i'm triing to set the deploy foulder to "Jboss deploy foulder" but the selection is disabled...is this a bug in Jboss tool or what?

I've attached a photo for more info:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the server must not have any modules attached then it alows to shnage the settings...it is also writen in the first line, I've overloked this line becuse in the previews versions of jboss tools this was not an issue.